# In texmaker on windows10, quickbuild doesnt work

Tags: texmaker

I was trying to open a file i recently created and got this pictured error:
[image: error image]

I tried loading a simple document and the error is still there. Has anyone else encountered this? The only change since i last loaded this file is uninstalling miktex. I have already tried reinstalling texmaker without success.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled miktex but had texworks and didnt know that both programs are needed to create and run latex files.

Comment: Texworks is an editor, it has nothing to do with your problem. Texmaker is simply telling you that it cannot find a latex installation to compile your document with. So make sure you've installed one